# Instantiating the ViewModel (simpleton assistance required)

Tags: wpf, mvvm

New to MVVM, it's clicking into place but I seem to have a knowledge/concept gap...

My MainWindow displays a list of items:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainWindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <vw:HeaderView Grid.Row="0" />

    <vw:RegistersView Grid.Row="1" />

    <vw:LogView Grid.Row="2" />
</Grid>
```

The MainWindowViewModel creates the main data repository.

The RegistersView has a ListView of objects (amongst other things) and is responsible for editing values.  I can get the data into the ListView in the RegistersView by exposing an ObservableCollection<> and changing the above line to

```
<vw:RegistersView DataContext="{Binding PropertyNameOfCollectionForListView}" Grid.Row="1" />
```

It seems very MVVM (not to mention obvious) to also create a ViewModel for the RegistersView ... but I'm lacking the insight into how to hook it up in a very basic way.  I understand that I *can* use IOC/DI using Unity, Prism and all the others but ... do I *have* to?  Really all I want is to be able to expose Registers-View specific properties to interact with the model and define commands to bind to, etc.

I feel like I want to say

```
<vw:RegistersView viewmodel="RegistersViewModel(PropertyNameOfCollectionForListView)" />
```

Can someone point me in the right direction please - I've read and read and read but I'm missing it.

Thanks for your patience ;->

Comment: i think you could also do: `<vw:RegistersView DataContext="{Binding Registers.RegisterViewModelCollection}"` where `Registers` is a `MainWindowViewModel` prop of type `RegistersViewModel`

Comment: Yes I think I'm getting the idea - basically my simple "the view creates the viewmodel" assumption was flawed. I'm off to have a play and will report back!!  Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `MainWindowViewModel` can expose property of `RegistersViewModel` type and then you can bind it to `RegisterView.DataContext` in the XAML as shown below:

```xml
<vw:RegistersView Grid.Row="1" 
                  DataContext="{Binding RegistersViewModelPropertyName}" />
```

Obviously `RegistersViewModelPropertyName` should reference to already instantiated `RegistersViewModel`. it's up to you how to do it, either on `MainViewModel` construction stage or implement `RegistersViewModelPropertyName` getter as lazy.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems very MVVM (not to mention obvious) to also create a ViewModel
>   for the RegistersView

I totally agree, this feels very MVVM like. So currently your `MainWindowViewModel` looks like the following:

```
class MainWindowViewModel
{
  public ObservableCollection<RegisterViewModel> PropertyNameOfCollectionForListView {get; set;}
}
```

Why not create a view model that encapsulates the collection of items being exposed to your UI together with their commands. So, the new view model might look like this:

```
public class RegistersViewModel
{
  public ObservableCollection<RegisterViewModel> RegisterViewModelCollection {get; set;}

  public ICommand AddRegister { get; set; }

  public ICommand RemoveRegister { get; set; }
}
```

i.e. it still exposes the original collection, but now adds commands that relate to this collection.

Your `MainWindowViewModel` now exposes this new view model:

```
class MainWindowViewModel
{
  public RegistersViewModel RegistersViewModelProperty {get; set;}
}
```

You then bind your usercontrol to this property:

And within the XAML for this user control bind to the list and the commands

```
<UserControl x:Class="RegistersView" ... >
   <ListView ItemsSource={Binding Path=RegisterViewModelCollection}/>
   <Button Content="Add" Command="{Binding Path=AddRegister}"/>
</UserControl>
```

And no, this does not need any DI or IoC!

Comment: And @sll I see what you're saying. The MainWindowBlah knows about its views and how to create them with the model it also knows about.  I need to play with this ... who needs sleep?  Thanks very much for the guidance.